# Unexpected behavior of ToBoundaryMesh and ToElementMesh

Tags: random, finite-element-method, mesh

This question is about functions `ToBoundaryMesh` and `ToElementMesh`. I use both functions successively because I need information about "Coordinates" and "MeshElements" as an input for function `SMTAddMesh` in AceFEM.

```
  << NDSolve`FEM`

    XIO = {{0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {2.5`, 0.`, 0.`}, {2.5`, 2.5`, 0.`}, {0.`, 
        2.5`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 2.5`}, {2.5`, 0.`, 2.5`}, {2.5`, 2.5`, 
        2.5`}, {0.`, 2.5`, 2.5`}};
    disksdata = {{{1.25`, 1.25`, 1.25`}, 0.9069579196494525`}};

    {xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, zmin, 
       zmax} = {Min[XIO[[All, 1]]], Max[XIO[[All, 1]]], 
        Min[XIO[[All, 2]]], Max[XIO[[All, 2]]], Min[XIO[[All, 3]]], 
        Max[XIO[[All, 3]]]} // N;

    disks = And @@ 
       Map[(x - #[[1, 1]])^2 + (y - #[[1, 2]])^2 + (z - #[[1, 
               3]])^2 >= #[[2]]^2 &, disksdata];

    n1 = Cross[XIO[[3]] - XIO[[4]], XIO[[1]] - XIO[[4]]];
    n2 = Cross[XIO[[2]] - XIO[[1]], XIO[[5]] - XIO[[1]]];
    n3 = Cross[XIO[[3]] - XIO[[2]], XIO[[6]] - XIO[[2]]];
    n4 = Cross[XIO[[4]] - XIO[[3]], XIO[[7]] - XIO[[3]]];
    n5 = Cross[XIO[[1]] - XIO[[4]], XIO[[8]] - XIO[[4]]];
    n6 = Cross[XIO[[6]] - XIO[[5]], XIO[[8]] - XIO[[5]]];

    regcond = 
      disks && n1.({x, y, z} - XIO[[4]]) <=  0 && 
       n2.({x, y, z} - XIO[[1]]) <=  0 && 
       n3.({x, y, z} - XIO[[2]]) <=  0 && 
       n4.({x, y, z} - XIO[[3]]) <=  0 && 
       n5.({x, y, z} - XIO[[4]]) <=  0 && n6.({x, y, z} - XIO[[5]]) <=  0;

    reg = ImplicitRegion[regcond, {x, y, z}];

    bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[reg, "MeshElementType" -> TetrahedronElement,
       "MeshOrder" -> 1, 
       MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 
          Min[xmax - xmin, ymax - ymin, zmax - zmin]/2}]
    bmesh["MeshElements"]
    bmesh["Coordinates"] // Length
```

`ToBoundaryMesh` gives result for number of coordiantes 680. If I use `ToElementMesh` where input is result of `ToBoundaryMesh`used before and the same options as before I get different number of coordiantes 817. I would like to know why is that?

```
elementmesh = 
 ToElementMesh[bmesh, "MeshElementType" -> TetrahedronElement,
  "MeshOrder" -> 1, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 
     Min[xmax - xmin, ymax - ymin, zmax - zmin]/2}]
elementmesh["MeshElements"]
elementmesh["Coordinates"] // Length
```

I would also like to know if there is a way how to make the same mesh if I run the code again, because now mesh is generated randomly and I get different mesh every time I run it. 
I also wonder if there is possibility to get actual "MeshElements" directly from `ToBoundaryMesh`, now I get Automatic as an answer.

Comment: I would say that `ToBoundaryMesh yields a triangle mesh, consisting solely of boundary vertices and boundary triangles while `ToElementMesh` yields a fulldimensional tetrahedron mesh, containing both the boundary and the interior vertices.

Comment: You get the actual triangles of `bmesh` with `bmesh["BoundaryElements"]` and you can see the mesh with `bmesh["Wireframe"]`

Comment: Any idea how to persuade  `ToElementMesh` to generte each time the same mesh?

Comment: Why do need `ToElementMesh` to generate mesh with the same number of elements each time? As long as the approximation to the boundary is good, there should be no problem? What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for your answers everyone, it is all clear now. I needed the same mesh to rule out some randomly appearing bug. I found a way around it, with simply saving already generated mesh and using it again.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand your question 100%. The fact that the number of coordinates is different is because one is a boundary mesh (only the hull is meshed) and the other is a full mesh. This full mesh also has interior coordinates which the boundary mesh does not have. This is documented in the [ElementMesh creation tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html) and the ref pages for [ToBoundaryMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToBoundaryMesh.html) and [ToElementMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToElementMesh.html)

For the second question, the randomness comes from the underlying tetrahedralization software TetGen. There is no way to control this from outside of TetGen. I think it would be more robust if your algorithm did not depend on the meshing algorithm to return an exact number of elements.