# Keeping mesh coordinates unchanged for Implict Region

Tags: differential-equations, graphics3d, finite-element-method, regions, mesh

I am trying to generate a 3D mesh for Finite Element simulations. I need to provide some precomputed inputs to the mesh points and will like my mesh to be the same for a given shape. However, everytime I run my code I am getting different numbers of nodes. Here is the example:

```
W = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, y, z}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[W, "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.02, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.1, "MeshQualityGoal" -> 1];
pts = mesh["Coordinates"];
Dimensions[pts]
```

The dimension of `pts` keeps on changing every time I run the code. I will like to obtain the same number every time. However, if I do the same problem as:

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[Ball[], "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.02, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.1, "MeshQualityGoal" -> 1];
pts = mesh["Coordinates"];
Dimensions[pts]
```

then the dimension does not change. While this is a viable solution for sphere/ellipsoids, I will need it to work for `ImplicitRegion` since I will be looking into more general surfaces. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of the other question you have found. This `W = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, y, z}];
m1 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[W];
m2 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[W];
MeshCoordinates[m1] == MeshCoordinates[m2]
False` produces the same issue and I believe that this is because of the underling TetGen (that does the (boundary) mesh generation) is not fully deterministic. I have asked coworkers for their opinion and if they do not come up with something else then there is not much that can be done. I'll keep you posted if I find anything new.

Comment: One other thought is to put this in the possible issues section

Comment: No, I agree. I found that discussion as well. You are right.

Comment: I have added an example of this to the reference page of `ToElementMesh` in the possible issues section. This will be available in the next version (13.2?)

Answer (score 3):

Include intermediate step `DiscretizeRegion[W]`

```
ToElementMesh[DiscretizeRegion[W] , "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 1/50,"MaxCellMeasure" -> 1/10, "MeshQualityGoal" -> 1]
(*ElementMesh[{{-0.99773, 0.99773}, {-0.99773, 0.99773},{-0.99773, 0.99773}}, {TetrahedronElement["<" 14405 ">"]}]*)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem. If you use: `Dimensions[%["Coordinates"]]` after your code then you will see that the dimension is changing every time you run it.

Comment: I meant running the code after clearing global variables.

Comment: What means " running the code after clearing global variables"?

Comment: Perhaps  `ToBoundaryMesh[W, "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.02, 
 "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.1, "MeshQualityGoal" -> 1]` is what you're looking for?

Comment: I meant running the code after restarting Mathematica or after clearing variables. But I guess there is a inherent randomness in the underlying meshing tool that cannot be controlled. After much digging I found a similar question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162461/unexpected-behavior-of-toboundarymesh-and-toelementmesh. Do you think that there is a way to get around this apart from saving the mesh?

Comment: I agree that the boundary mesh can be regenerated every time with same points. However I need to solve a volume (or bulk) problem and it seems like that cannot be generated with same points.

Comment: If you know `pts` you can create a mesh without additional points: Try  `DelaunayMesh[pts]["MakeRepresentation"["ElementMesh"]]`